# Why "let" is not listed in the keywords of ECMAScript 2019 (ES10)?

Tags: javascript

In ECMAScript 2019 one can use `let` to declare a new (lexical binding) variable. (Specification section 13.3.1 https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#prod-LexicalDeclaration )

Why does the list of keywords not contain `let`
( https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#prod-Keyword
also in section 11.6.2.1)?

Comment: I do not know exactly why. My guess though is that it has to do with that "A variable defined by a LexicalBinding with an Initializer is assigned the value of its Initializer's AssignmentExpression when the LexicalBinding is evaluated, not when the variable is created. If a LexicalBinding in a let declaration does not have an Initializer the variable is assigned the value undefined when the LexicalBinding is evaluated."

Comment: There is "A static semantics rule ensures that this form of LexicalBinding never occurs in a const declaration." this difference can be related as of why that have chosen to sort the let as a reserved word rather than a strict keyword.

Comment: Backward compatibility. `var let = 1` is valid because it might be used in old code while `let let = 1` will throw a SyntaxError.

Comment: @str your explain is reasonable. I guess that `const` was defined in an earlier version of EcmaScript as a keyword but was not assigned to a semantic. So `const` now listed in list of keyword and also implemented by major browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list of Javascript reserved words was fixed back in 2000 in the [3rd edition of the spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) (page 14). For backwards compatibility it's not possible to extend this list, because that would break existing programs. However, the spec authors couldn't predict how the language will evolve back then, and which new keywords will be needed. As a result, some "newer" keywords are not reserved, unless the strict mode is used.

```
var let = 1; // valid in the non-strict mode
```

Technically this means that `let`, `await`, `yield` etc are not "tokens" for the compiler but just identifiers, which are given special meaning only in specific syntactic positions and treated as is otherwise (again, in the non-strict mode):

```
function *yield() { // identifier
    yield 1; // keyword
}

var let = 1; // identifier
let x = 2; // keyword
```

The strict mode treats "old" and "new" reserved words equally, although error messages are different ("unexpected token" vs "strict mode reserved word").